# How to get smooth & low-density wireframe

Tags: modeling, wireframe

Hi guys I'm trying to constrcut a web using the wireframe modifier. I hope to get a smooth contour so a subdivision modifier was added before wireframe modifier, and this is the result:

[image]

However I don't need such a high density of the wireframe. So is there any method to selectively solidfy some of these wires?

OR how can I smooth the wireframe below (without subdivision modifier)?
[image]

Hope my question is clear... 
Any relavant suggestions or solutions are appreciated! Thanks ><

Answer (score 1):

If you throw a "Decimate" modifier in "Un-subdivide" mode (shown here: 2 iterations) in-between the Subdivide and Wireframe Modifiers, I think that gets roughly what you described.

[image: Kind of smooth-ish wireframe]

Comment: Nice :). Just to add  - *two iterations* are needed to Un-subdivide *one level* of Subdivision.